# Why does this date conversion cause an error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Why does this fail?

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '3/3/2021', 1)
```

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: Try `101` for the style.

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) answers your question and should always be your first port of call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because format style = 1 means `mm/dd/yy` date format i.e. only a 2 digit year.

```
  1 = mm/dd/yy
101 = mm/dd/yyyy
```

You want to use the 101 style.

See the complete list of formatting styles here [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(CONVERT_TSQL);k(sql13.swb.tsqlresults.f1);k(sql13.swb.tsqlquery.f1);k(MiscellaneousFilesProject);k(DevLang-TSQL)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=sql-server-ver15)